# NgRepeat Not Working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have tried doing a trivial usage of ng-repeat and even that is not working. Is there something I need to load. I have included

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
```

Below is the trivial example

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43]">
    {{n}}
</div>
```

It prints nothing out.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think dupe values are allowed. Try this:

```
    <html ng-app="app" >

            <div ng-repeat="n in [41, 42, 43, 44]">
                 {{n}}
              </div>



            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

            <script>

                var app = angular.module("app", []);

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add track by $index it will display the duplicate values.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
    {{n}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either upgrade angular from 1.2 so you can use `track by $index` in the `ng-repeat` expression or change data to array of objects

Answer (score 0):

There array shouldn't have any duplicate values to run your code.
It should be like

```
<div ng-repeat="n in ['42', '43', '44', '45']">
     {{n}}
  </div>
```

The below code will work

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
     {{n}}
  </div>
```